# how to show form on button click using jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I want my form to appear when i click on the button sign up

```
<div id="signup">
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"  method="POST"  id="form1">
        <input name="user" type="text" placeholder="Username" size="30" >
        <input name="pass" type="password" placeholder="Password"  size="30" >
        <input class="btn" type="submit" value="sign up" name="signup">
</div>
```

this is the jQuery code:

```
<script>
$( "#form" ).click(function() {
  $( "#signup" ).show( "Clip", 1000 );
});
</script>
```

Comment: Proper code indentation highlights that you haven't closed your form tag (to start with). Secondly, you should bind the click event to the `$('input[name="signup"]')` button, or give the button a unique ID to bind to. I haven't seen anyone binding a click to a form element before... seems wrong. Thirdly, it looks like the button you click to show the form is within the div that you show when you click the button (chicken & egg?) The way I see it, you want [something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/gb035b9c/)

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try something like this...(notice I have added an extra "button" to your HTML and closed the "form" tag

CSS...

```
#form1 {
 display : none;
}
button {
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

HTML...

```
<div id="signup">
<button id="signup">Click here to sign-up!</button>
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"  method="POST"  id="form1">
        <input name="user" type="text" placeholder="Username" size="30" >
        <input name="pass" type="password" placeholder="Password"  size="30" >
        <input class="btn" type="submit" value="sign up" name="signup">
    </form>
</div>
```

then using JQuery...

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
  $( "#signup" ).click( function() {
    $( "#form1" ).toggle( 'slow' );
  });
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zfohLL0a/)

Hope this helps. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

first of all  you haven't closed your form tag, second your targeting an element with a id 'form' and any of the elements you have has such id, now  one thing you could do is to give each input element in your form a class(signup_txt for example) and target those elements using css and set the property 'display' to none to hide them like this:

```
.signup_txt{
   display:none
}
```

then give your submit button an id (signup_btn for example) and do this:

```
$("#signup_btn").click(function(){
  $(".signup_txt").show(); 
});
```

and that should do the job here's an demo in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zdksn35f/